# How to ask to repeat a question after QA section politely?

Tags: expressions, politeness

When you are a speaker on a conference and somebody asks you a question which you didn't quite understood or which is too complicated to give a short answer the common practice is to answer something like "Could you please find me after this talk and I try to answer you then?". In Russian there is a word for this - 'в кулуарах', from French word 'couloir', corridor. It is translated as 'on the sidelines' according to Google Translate. Still I never heard such an expression from a native speaker and apparently it has something to do with baseball, not conferences.

So what would native speaker usually say in such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has more to do with American football rather than baseball!

Anyway, you could say

> That's a great question. Could you please ask it to me individually?

or

> Could you please ask it to me after the  presentation.

or

> I would be happy to answer that question after the presentation (after my talk).

You could add

> I'll be in such-and-such place, or You can find me in such-and-such place.

where such-and-such place could be the snack line, a book table, the company's product table, etc.

You could use your sentence, with one change:

> Could you please find me after this talk and I will try to answer you then?

Answer (score 2):

The **speaker** or the **introducer** may something to the effect of

> *So-and-so* will be around after the Q&A if you want to come speak to them

to alert the audience that questions will be answered, and the speaker is will to hang around to answer them and meet the audience

These requests but the speaker during a Q&A usually consists of several parts which in general are:

**An acknowledgement**

> Good question
>   That's a great question
>   Thank you for your question

**A reason for not answering immediately**

> That's a very **specific** question for this audience
>   There's a lot of **detail** in your question
>   I don't really want to get **side-tracked**

**What to do**

> why don't we discuss this afterwards
>   come see me afterwards
>   let's talk about this afterwards
>   if you could come see me afterwards

**A closing** where the speaker might say

> I'll still be around to answer any further questions

Answer (score 1):

We'd generally just mention that we'd like to discuss it afterwards: usually with a short explanation for politeness sake. Something like:

> That's a great question but perhaps a little specific to answer right now, could we discuss it after the presentation?

or

> I don't actually have those numbers with me, but if you give me your email address during the break I'd be happy to forward them to you.

or

> To answer that would probably take more time than I have right now, but we could speak about it after if you'd like.

You could skip the explanation and just stick to the "Can we discuss this after the presentation", although this can sometimes come across as defensive and suggest you don't actually know the answer.